# completeness and soundness in $\lambda$-caclulus

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I many times encountered the concept of soundness and completeness in proof related articles, such as type system, logic.
[description of these two concepts in logic](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2800/2016sp/lectures/lec39-sound-complete.html)

I had a discussion recently and that appeared again, but in a topic related to $lambda$-calculus. I could not imagine these two concepts in $\lambda$-calculus as clear as the above link description of their meaning.

Note that I know the soundness and completeness of the type systems.
I am asking in terms of untyped $\lambda$-calculus. 
Could anyone point out any good article about it or explain to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue involves [Semantics of λ-calculus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/#SemLCal).

Comment: Maybe useful the review: Felice Cardone & JRoger Hindley, [History of lambda-calculus and combinatory logic](http://www.users.waitrose.com/~hindley/SomePapers_PDFs/2006CarHin,HistlamRp.pdf) (2006), **Ch.9 Models for λ**.

Comment: More details into: H.P. Barendregt, [The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZdydJZVue50C) (1985), **Ch.18 Construction of Models**.

Comment: I think that can be also udeful JRoger Hindley, [The completeness theorem for typing λ-terms](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397583901366) (1983)

Comment: Finally, see **Sec 17A. Realizability interpretation of types** of Henk Barendregt & Wil Dekkers, [Lambda Calculus with Types](https://books.google.it/books?id=2UVasvrhXl8C&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge UP (2010).